# Updating a reference to a child object in Entity framework 4.1 (CodeFirst)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I'm trying to update an object that I have previously saved with EntityFramework 4.1 (CodeFirst)

The class Job has the following properties ...

```
public class Job
{
    [key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public JobType JobType { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The initial create works fine, but the update only commits changes to the strings..

If I change the child objects eg the `JobType` Property from `JobTypeA` to `JobTypeB` - the change is not committed ...

I'm not looking to commit a change to JobType - only to Job.

```
using (var context = new JobContext())
{
    context.Jobs.Attach(job);
    context.Entry(job).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Having a look at SQL Profiler - the Ids are not even being sent for the Update - however they are for the initial insert!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Setting the state to `Modified` only updates scalar and complex properties, not your navigation properties. This only goes through Entity Framework's change detection. It means that you need to load the original from the database:

```
using (var context = new JobContext())
{
    var originalJob = context.Jobs.Include(j => j.JobType)
        .Single(j => j.Id == job.Id);

    // Update scalar/complex properties
    context.Entry(originalJob).CurrentValues.SetValues(job);

    // Update reference
    originalJob.JobType = job.JobType;

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

You could probably also leverage some "tricks" in your case:

```
using (var context = new JobContext())
{
    var jobType = job.JobType;
    job.JobType = null;

    context.JobTypes.Attach(jobType);
    context.Jobs.Attach(job);
    // change detection starts from here,
    // EF "thinks" now, original is JobType==null

    job.JobType = jobType;
    // change detection will recognize this as a change
    // and send an UPDATE to the DB

    context.Entry(job).State = EntityState.Modified; // for scalar/complex props

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

It wouldn't work though if you want to set `JobType` to `null`.

This is a typical situation which is getting much simpler if you expose foreign keys as properties in your model: With a `JobTypeId` in your `Job` entity your code would work because the FK property is scalar and setting the state to `Modified` will also mark this property as modified.

Comment: "This is a typical situation which is getting much simpler if you expose foreign keys as properties in your model"
THIS. This should be included in every EF-tutorial. It's unbeliavable how it makes things "just work".

Comment: @EugenTimm How does that work when updating a detached? Do you update the navigation property, or the FK?