# Entity Reference updating issue in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am facing the entity updating issue in entity framework. In my code, first I am creating an **employee** object,  set all properties to include scalar and navigation property, in the same method, I m update **candidate entity** and their navigation property User, but when I am going to save all entity, no scalar property get updated, and navigation property are remain same, why this happened, please explain me this scenario.

Here my code

```
public void AddEmployee(int candidateId)
{ 
    var candidate= candidateRepository.read(candidateId);
    var employee= new Employee();
     /*--- add property ---*/
    candidate.Employee= employee;
    candidate.User.IsPlaced = true;
    employeeRepository.add(employee);
    candidateRepository.update(candidate);
}
```

Here my repository update method

```
public void update(T entity)
{
     scope.Container.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
     scope.Container.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
     scope.Container.Savechanges();
}
public void read(int Id)
{
    scope.Container.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id);
}
```

In this only employee add in database, candidate repository update method does't work, please explain me this behaviour.

Comment: this working fine if I m directly use the container in the method, but I use repository update method, it does not track navigation property changes

Comment: In your first block of code, where does `candidate` come from?  Is that a class or module-level variable?

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850774/updating-a-reference-to-a-child-object-in-entity-framework-4-1-codefirst

Comment: I think so, but why candidate entity changes are not tracked by the container ?

Comment: You write that "no scalar property get updated" but you are not changing any scalar in `candidate`, you are changing a scalar in `candidate.User`

Comment: did you tried to use include when reading the candidate . ? something like   var candidate=  context.Candidates.Include("Employee").FirstOrDefault(s=>s.id= candidateId)

Comment: Also if you can give the model classes and dbcontect calss it wil lbe easrier to answer

Comment: include does not help, my question is understand this behavior of update entity, if I used container then all work good everything is updated correctly, but when I use repository method it only updates selected entity, why?