# Entity Framework Many to many data not persisting

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have strange problem with entity framework. I'm trying to update my entity `User` which has many-to-many relation with `Team`. When I try to add some team (which exists in database) to the user nothing changes in the database. However when I remove all teams from the user it is persiting to database and the user is free of any team. Why adding is not persisting? Any ideas?

```
  public int Save(User entity)
    {
        using (var context = new UsersContext())
        {
                var teamIds = entity.Teams.Select(t => t.Id).ToArray();
                context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
                context.Entry(entity).Collection(u => u.Teams).Load();
                entity.Teams.Clear();
                foreach (var teamId in teamIds)
                {
                    entity.Teams.Add(context.Teams.Find(teamId));
                }

            return context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, the moment you call `context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;`, the referenced `Team` entries will be set to `State = EntityState.Unchanged`, the collection will not be recognized as modified, EF will ignore the attempt to get the actual database values via `context.Entry(entity).Collection(u => u.Teams).Load();` and it will also not recognize the changes with clear and re-add, because `context.Teams.Find(teamId)` will return the local entries that where already marked unchanged and the collection at the end will contain the same data as it did initially.

Possible Solution: clear collection before setting State Modified, then load the collection from database and clear again before re-adding your items:

```
using (var context = new DbC())
{
    var teamIds = entity.Teams.Select(t => t.Id).ToArray();
    entity.Teams.Clear();
    context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.Entry(entity).Collection(u => u.Teams).Load();
    entity.Teams.Clear();
    foreach (var teamId in teamIds)
    {
        entity.Teams.Add(context.Teams.Find(teamId));
    }
    return context.SaveChanges();
}
```

See here for a somewhat similar topic: [Updating a reference to a child object in Entity framework 4.1 (CodeFirst)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7850774/5265292) even though it is about a single reference rather than a collection, the basic problem is the same.

A quote from documentation regarding the `Collection(..).Load()`:

> Loads the collection of entities from the database.  Note that entities that
>   already exist in the context are not overwritten with values from the database.

This is part of why loading is not effective to get the actual database state, when the collection is initially filled.

Comment: That almost worked. To make it fully working I needed to add one more 'entity.Teams.Clear()' after collection loading. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Crekate oh yea, dumb me... I did test my code but in a way where I only added more teams to the existing - so there was no real need to clear in my case :O